# Is there any Bootsrap Carousel on ready callback or something similar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap carousel's on most of my apps and I love them they are fast and easy to setup. I just have one problem:

- As the site is loading the carousel has no height (because the images havent loaded)
- As the images load the carousel "jumps" or increases to the height of
  the images

What I am hoping to do is implement a loader gif whilst bootstraps images are still loading?

At the moment I have a loader gif which is called before the document is ready, which works ok but when the page is quite long then the carousel will apear to be 'loading' because there are more images further down the page which are still loading. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try applying following logic

1) Assuming that your carousel has 4 images like:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img_flower1.jpg" alt="Flower" onload="javascript:imageloaded(1);" >
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" onload="javascript:imageloaded(2);">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower3.jpg" alt="Flower" onload="javascript:imageloaded(3);">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower4.jpg" alt="Flower" onload="javascript:imageloaded(4);">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here we have added a `onload` function call.

2) Create global level JavaScript array

```
var loadedImages = [];
```

3) `function imageloaded()` will have something like this:

```
function imageloaded(imgNumber)
{
    if($.inArray(imgNumber, loadedImages ) == -1)
    {
        loadedImages.push(imgNumber);
    }

    if(loadedImages.length == 4) //number of images/item you have in your carousel
    {
        //Write here logic to hide 'loading' symbol and show bootstrap carousel
    }
}
```